# show div after => second click of any form element

Tags: javascript

*This is seeking a solution using second click or `click` counting; not a duplicate from other question considering `onchange` solution.*

---

I'm trying to simply show a div after any form element was clicked a second time in vanilla JS. The context is; if the form has been updated I want to show a notification to refresh their quote. So if the user has gone back and clicked any form element a second time; que the div.

I have the below for counting clicks; but how could I limit this to only all my form elements (I don't need this to fire after clicking a second time on anything, just the form).

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input, select, textarea, option, optgroup, fieldset, label").addEventListener("click", clickFormTwo);

var currentLetter = 0;
var intervalID;
var clickCount = 0; 
var updateRate = document.querySelector('.updateRate');

function clickFormTwo {
    if  (!isStart) {
        clickCount++;
        if (clickCount == 1) {
            // first click stuff
        }
        if (clickCount == 2) {
          updateRate.style.display = "block";
        }
    }       
}
```

***Context:***
*It is an inline quote tool; a quote will generate inline after form elements are filled out. I was trying to create a 'banner' that would que if a user has adjusted any web form element a second time. Sorry for the confusion.*

---

**Updated attempt:**

```
document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, option, optgroup, fieldset, label").addEventListener("click", clickFormTwo);

var currentLetter = 0;
var intervalID;
var clickCount = 0; 
var updateRate = document.querySelector('.updateRate'); 
var clickCount = 0;

function clickFormTwo(e) {
  clickCount++;
  if (clickCount === 1) {
    // first click stuff
    e.preventDefault();


  } else if (clickCount === 2) {
    clickCount = 0;
    updateRate.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

**Console error:**

```
VM443:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:89
```

---

html/css context

```
<div class="updateRate">Update Rate</div>

<style>
.updateRate { 
   display:none;
   top: 0px;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0px;
   z-index: 11111;
}
#rate, .updateRate { 
    background: #354563;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: So I see no click event listener....

Comment: > limit this to only all my form elements <  I think your language is confusing. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Yeah, so 'input, select, radio, etc'

Comment: Please post the code for the click event listener! You can limit it to only fire after the click on the `form` elements.

Comment: So bind click handler to form?

Comment: Why don't you automatically refresh the quote `onchange` any of the elements. That might be easier.

Comment: @Andy thanks but I'd need to add onchange to the HTML of all elements with this, right?

Comment: As of you are doing for clicks. Just onchange => refresh quote. In that case you always know that something was changed. Even if user just clicking on the form an nothing changed - onchange will work perfectly.

Comment: @extempl so I just implemented it with onchange; now the problem is it 'shows' or fires after the first initial time filling out the form, I want it to be if the user goes back and alters anything: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012618/show-div-banner-after-onchange-of-any-form-elems

Comment: So, the user enters some data, press submit, and then, if something changed after this - show banner? Then you should set `onchange` handlers on form `submit`. Please, describe the entire task what you are expecting from it in details in that issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show div banner after onchange of any form elems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012618/show-div-banner-after-onchange-of-any-form-elems)

Answer (score 0):

The function should be like this

```js
var clickCount = 0;

function clickFormTwo(e) {
  clickCount++;
  if (clickCount === 1) {
    // first click stuff
    e.preventDefault();


  } else if (clickCount === 2) {
    clickCount = 0;
    updateRate.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: It's returning an error and still not a running solution; Thanks though! I have updated the question in more detail, if interested!

Comment: You have itrate over query slector, since `querySelectorAll` returns an array of nodes, try this `document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, option, optgroup, fieldset, label").forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", clickFormTwo))`