# Show div banner after onchange of any form elems

Tags: javascript

**JS:**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input, select, textarea, option, optgroup, fieldset, label").onchange = function () {
     var updateRate = document.querySelector('.updateRate');    
     updateRate.style.display = "block";
};
```

**mark-up & styles:**

```
<div class="updateRate">Update Rate</div>

<style>
.updateRate { 
   display:none;
   top: 0px;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0px;
   z-index: 11111;
}
#rate, .updateRate { 
    background: #354563;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

*The above is my attempt; but the banner is still not displaying after any form elements state change.*

---

**Update:** So both SO answers below seem to be correct; but perhaps I didn't explain the context enough - now the 'banner' displays as soon as the form is beginning to be filled out the first time; the goal was for the banner to show after a user has gone back in and updated a form element (second time, or changing it from initial).

---

***Context:***
*It is an inline quote tool; a quote will generate inline after form elements are filled out. I was trying to create a 'banner' that would que if a user has adjusted any web form element a second time. Sorry for the confusion.*

Comment: Please add the related HTML.

Comment: `user has gone back` - describe this in more detail. Back from where? Different page? Another tab? Change after submitting the form?

Comment: It is an inline quote tool; a quote will generate inline after form elements are filled out. I was trying to create a 'refresh button' that would que if a user has adjusted any web form element a second time. Sorry for the confusion. My initial approach was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011986/show-div-after-second-click-of-any-form-element?noredirect=1#comment92929043_53011986

Answer (score 2):

You can't attach the event this way since ***the `getElementsByTagName` method accept one single tag name*** you could use the **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** method instead to get the elements then loop through them using `foreach` and attach the event using `addEventListener()`:

```js
var fields = document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, option, optgroup, fieldset, label");

[].forEach.call(fields, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', showUpdateRate, false);
});

function showUpdateRate() {
  if (document.querySelector('.quote').textContent != "") {
    document.querySelector('.updateRate').style.display = "block";
  }
}

document.querySelector('.generate').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var quote = document.querySelector('[name="type"]:checked').value;
  document.querySelector('.quote').textContent = quote + " Quote";
});
```

```css
.updateRate {
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 11111;
}

#rate,
.updateRate {
  background: #354563;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="updateRate">Update Rate</div>

<br><br><br>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="Success">Success
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="Motivation">Motivation
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="Work">Work
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" class="generate" value="Generate">
</form>
<br>
<span class="quote"></span>
```

Comment: Could you please describe more what you mean by your update

Comment: Not all browsers support calling `.forEach()` on a node list. It is recommended to formally convert it to an Array first.

Comment: _a quote will generate inline after form elements are filled out_ this quote will be generated by a button click?! and where it will be shown?

Comment: Check my updated snippet @No-Spex ... It will show "banner" just if the quote is already generated and the user changes the inputs...

Answer (score 1):

[`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a node list (an array-like object), not a single element. As such, it doesn't have an `onchange` property to work with. After getting the node list, you'll need to loop over all the items in the list and set up the event handler for each, one at a time.

Also, `.getElementsByTagName()` only allows for a single tag name to be passed in, not a comma separated list. Additionally, it returns a "live node list", which has performance implications, so if you aren't dynamically adding/removing elements, you should avoid it and use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead.

Now, `option`, `optgroup`, and `label` elements can only be changed via code, and don't emit or recieve a `change` event in the first place, so you actually don't want/need those included in your node list.

More comments about how to make your code more modern and organized inline below:

```js
// Get this reference just once and cache it in a variable
var updateRate = document.querySelector('.updateRate');  

// Gather up all the relevant elements into a node list
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, fieldset");

// Convert the node list into an Array so that .forEach() 
// can safely be used to loop in all modern browsers
Array.prototype.slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element){
  // Add event listeners the modern way, not with .onXyz properties
  element.addEventListener("change", function () {  
    // Just remove the hidden class already applied to the element
    // instead of working with inline styles
    updateRate.classList.remove("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
/*
   This is applied to the "Update Rate" element in HTML by default.
   It can be removed by the JavaScript when appropriate. 
*/
.hidden { display:none; }

.updateRate { 
   top: 0px;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0px;
   z-index: 11111;
}

#rate, .updateRate { 
    background: #354563;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>This is the legend</legend>
    <input>
    <select>
      <option>choice 1</option>
      <option>choice 2</option>
      <option>choice 3</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
 <textarea></textarea>
</form>

<!-- Set this element to be hidden by default -->
<div class="updateRate" class="hidden">Update Rate</div>
```